# array_search() in PHP 5.4 different?

Tags: php

My script was working fine, then I upgraded to PHP 5.4 on my server and I get:

> Illegal string offset 'param_name'

Here is the code, I don't know what the compatibility issue is:

```
 if(!empty($attributes['params'])) {
                $attributes_keys = Array();
                foreach($attributes['params'] as $attribute) {
                    $key = array_search($attribute['param_name'], $attributes_keys);
                    if( $key === false ) {
                        $attributes_keys[] = $attribute['param_name'];
                        self::$sc[$name]['params'][] = $attribute;
                    } else {
                        self::$sc[$name]['params'][$key] = $attribute;
                    }
                }
            }
```

**UPDATE**:

So I added `die(var_dump($attribute));` after the `foreach` statement and this is the output i got:

> array(5) { ["type"]=> string(9) "textfield" ["heading"]=> string(16) "Extra class name" ["param_name"]=> string(8) "el_class" ["value"]=> string(0) "" ["description"]=> string(139) "description text here" }

Is there a mod I can do that can make this compatible in PHP 5.4 ?

Comment: `$attribute` is a string. You should find out why it's not an array! You likely have a problem somewhere earlier in your script.

Comment: Put `die(var_dump($attribute));` over `$key =` in your foreach and show us your result.

Comment: If you receive an error after a PHP upgrade where you didn't get one before, this may be due to different error_reporting settings in php.ini.

Comment: so i added die(var_dump($attribute)); over $key = in your foreach so everyone can see what the 'array' looks like